# como saber si un proceso almacenado esta mal o mi funcion de php

Tags: php, sql-server, php7, sql-server-2008, sqlsrv

tengo un proceso almacenado en una base de datos MSSQL que ejecuto de esta manera
`EXEC sp_Procesar_Balance '003','.','20190101','20191231',0,0,0,'00'` 
hasta alli todo bien. ahora debo llamar este proceso almacenado con php lo cual lo ejecuto de esta manera.

```
      $conn = new Conectar();
      $cid=$conn->conexion();
      $parametros = array(
      array(&$_SESSION['INGRESO']['item'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
      array(&$_SESSION['INGRESO']['periodo'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
      array(&$desde, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
      array(&$hasta, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
      array(&$EsCoop, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
      array(&$sucursal, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
      array(&$balanceMes, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
      array(&$cc, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
      );

     $sql="EXEC sp_Procesar_Balance @Item=?, @Periodo=?, @FechaDesde=?, @FechaHasta=?, @EsCoop=?, @ConSucursal=?, @EsBalanceMes=?, @CentroCostos=? ";
     
      $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($cid, $sql,$parametros);
      if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
   
         echo "Error en consulta PA.\n";         
         $respuesta = -1;
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
         return $respuesta;  
       die;
      }
      $respuesta =  1;
        return $respuesta;      
    }
```

los parametros que recibe la funcion los mismos. Se ejecuta la funcion pero de 236 registros que existe solo aparecen 3.
al ejecutar  la funcion no no arroja ningun error.

esta mal la funcion o el proceso almacenado?

Comment: Cuando imprimes `$sql` sale la consulta como esperas? Si ejecutas eso en MSSQL directo, salen los 236 registros?

Comment: `$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($cid, $sql,$parametros);`  lo prepara y lo asocia con los parametros y ejecuta. asi que al mandar `$sql` a imprimir me daria literalmente o que esta alli.
probe con  `$sql="EXEC sp_Procesar_Balance @Item='003', @Periodo='.', @FechaDesde='20190101', @FechaHasta='20191231', @EsCoop=0, @ConSucursal=0, @EsBalanceMes=0, @CentroCostos='00' "; ` y ejecutarlo con `$stmt = sqlsrv_query($cid, $sql);` y me da el mismo resultado cabe recalcar que `$cid` es la conexion

Comment: ¿Dónde estás leyendo los datos? No veo ese código.